# Casting enums in a class

Tags: java, enums

I have five cases of enums that look like this one below:

```
public enum Answers{
    A(0), B(1), C(2), D(3), E(4);

    Answers(int code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    protected int code;

    public int getCode(){
        return this.code;
    }
}
```

They all are all virtually the same except consisting of different "codes" and enumerators. I now have this following class where the generic is an extension of an Enum, however, I need to be able to use the `getCode()`, which is only in my enums, not a basic enum.

```
public class test<T extends Enum>{
    public void tester(T e){
        System.out.println(e.getCode()); //I want to be able to do this, 
                                         //however, the basic enum does don't
                                         //have this method, and enums can't extend
                                         //anything.
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your enums implement an interface:

```
public interface Coded {
    int getCode();
}
```

Then:

```
public enum Answers implements Coded {
    ...
}
```

And:

```
public class Test<T extends Enum & Coded> {
    public void tester(T e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `extends something & somethingother` belong to Java7? I've never seen this before

Comment: @BackSlash: Nope. It exists since the generics were introduced: Java 5.

Answer (score 2):

Make all your enums implement a common interface:

```
public interface HasCode {
    int getCode();
}

public enum Answers implements HasCode {
    ...
}
```

And then

```
public class Test<T extends HasCode> {
```

Answer (score 2):

Have your enum classes implement your own `HasCode` interface:

```
public interface HasCode {
    public int getCode();
}

public enum Answers implements HasCode {
//...
```

Then you can restrict `T` to be a `HasCode`:

```
public class test<T extends HasCode>{
```

and then Java will recognize that anything, even an `enum`, as long it implements `HasCode`, will have a `getCode()` method and it can be called in `tester`.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the only method you want to add to your Enum then you don't have to do it. Every Enum already has [`ordinal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) method which returns value that represents it position in Enum. Take a look at this example

```
enum Answers{
    A,B,C,D,E;
}

class EnumTest<T extends Enum<T>>{
    public void tester(T e){
        System.out.println(e.ordinal()); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EnumTest<Answers> t = new EnumTest<>();
        t.tester(Answers.A);
        t.tester(Answers.B);
        t.tester(Answers.E);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
4
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and actually extremely helpful for another part of this project I was doing. However, I should specified this in in the question, but the codes don't necessarily apply to the enumerators position. But I do think this is/will be helpful for others.